# Is there any difference between the size of a cricket ball for men and women in cricket? if yes then Why?

Tags: cricket, trivia

Cricket ball is heavy weighted in both cases for men and women but is there any difference between the size of cricket ball that is used for women and men? if the answer is yes then what the reason behind this difference?

Answer (score 0):

The weight of the ball in women's cricket must be in between(139.98 to 150.61 grams). Whereas for men it is somewhere between (Appx 155.9–163 gm)

https://www.quora.com/How-is-women%E2%80%99s-cricket-different-than-mens-cricket

https://www.quora.com/Does-women-cricketers-use-the-same-kind-of-hard-ball-used-by-mens-cricketers

womans are considered weaker than men that's why the ball is lesser in weight

Answer (score 0):

The laws are perfectly clear. Women's cricket uses a ball that has slightly less mass and may be slightly smaller than the ball used for men's cricket.

> **4.1 Weight and size**
>
> The ball, when new, shall weigh not less than 5.5 ounces/155.9 g, nor more than 5.75 ounces/163 g, and shall measure not less than 8.81 in/22.4 cm, nor more than 9 in/22.9 cm in circumference.
>
> ...
>
> **4.6 Specifications**
>
> The specifications as described in 4.1 shall apply to men’s cricket only.  The following specifications shall apply to:
>
> **4.6.1** Women’s cricket
>
> Weight: from 4.94 ounces/140 g to 5.31 ounces 151 g
>
> Circumference: from 8.25 in/21.0 cm to 8.88 in/22.5 cm.

The difference is due to traditionalist views of women as a physically weaker sex requiring some allowance for their perceived inability to handle "proper" equipment.